# Headlessui Disclosure Typescript error: 'TypeError: close is not a function'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I encountered this problem while trying to implement a `button` inside the Disclosure panel, which should close the disclosure.
According to the [Headlessui docs](https://headlessui.dev/react/disclosure#closing-disclosures-manually) we can just make use of `close` from Headlessui if we want to close a disclosure manually when clicking a child of its panel. Indeed, it works fine with `react`, but couldn't figure out how to solve it with typescript.
It throws this error while clicking the button inside the `panel`:

```
TypeError: close is not a function
```

Here is the code

```
import { Disclosure } from "@headlessui/react";

import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Disclosure>
      {() => (
        <div>
          <Disclosure.Button>
            <span>modal</span>
            <ExpandMoreIcon />
          </Disclosure.Button>

          <Disclosure.Panel>
            {({ close }) => (
              <div>
                <button onClick={() => close()}>
                  <CloseIcon />
                </button>

                <div>modal panel</div>
              </div>
            )}
          </Disclosure.Panel>
        </div>
      )}
    </Disclosure>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Your code seems to run for me, what version of headlessui are you using?

Comment: @BrendanBond thanks for the answer, it is "@headlessui/react": "^1.0.0"

Comment: My package.json reads ^1.4.0, try upgrading the library

Comment: @BrendanBond ok, I will try it as well